# What is the easiest, no-frills way to produce a simple video on Windows 8?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-recording

My laptop has a camera. Since it can obviously take video of me (a la Skyping), it should be easy to create a video of myself (I am going to create a short video for a Kickstarter project).

My laptop runs Windows 7 and 8.

All I'm going to do is stand or sit in front of it and talk for a couple of minutes. What is the easiest way to accomplish that using apps that come with Windows or something free that I can download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for super simple and free. The Windows 8 Camera App will allow you to record video files which it then saves to the Pictures->Camera Roll folder.  It's no frills but will do the trick in a pinch.

When you open the Camera App there are two buttons one that looks like a video camera and one a still camera.  You click the video camera button and it starts recording immediately. When you're finished you click the button again and the video is saved to the location mentioned above.

Comment: Perfect, thanks - sounds like just what the non-doctor (me) ordered.

Comment: And you can use Windows Movie Maker to trim the start and the end, so there's not awkward silence or footage of you pressing keys and clicking around. Windows Movie Maker comes free with Windows.